# java.lang.NullPointerException in doinbackground

Tags: java, android

[image]This is the code in java,I did a debug and it stops where `apPhoto[i].id = Integer.parseInt(us.getPropertyAsString(0));`,the getproperty returns null :

```
@Override
    protected ApartmentPhoto[] doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME1);
        PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
        pi.setNamespace(NAMESPACE);
        pi.setName("email");
        pi.setValue(Global.Email);
        pi.setType(String.class);
        request.addProperty(pi);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        try {
            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(
                    Global.URL);
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION1, envelope);

            SoapObject result11 = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
            if (result11 == null)
                return null;
            else {
                ApartmentPhoto[] apPhoto = new ApartmentPhoto[result11.getPropertyCount()];
                for (int i = 0; i < apPhoto.length; i++) {
                    SoapObject us = (SoapObject) result11.getProperty(i);

                    apPhoto[i] = new ApartmentPhoto();
                     apPhoto[i].id = Integer.parseInt(us.getPropertyAsString(0));
                    apPhoto[i].image = us.getPropertyAsString(3);
                }
                return apPhoto;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

            return null;

        }
    }
}


private class ApartmentPhoto {
    public String email1;
    public int id;
    public String image;
}
```

Comment: Is the Integer itself null or is that line throwing a nullpointerexception?

Comment: @k_g us is not null but this one *Integer.parseInt(us.getPropertyAsString(0));* is null..

Comment: Can you please post the stack trace?

Comment: I know `us` is not null. However, is `us.getPropertyAsString(0)` null?

Comment: @Tgsmith61591 what is the stack trace?

Comment: The stack trace is the list of method calls that you should be getting from your debugger/LogCat

Comment: You even have it in your catch block: `e.printStackTrace();`. It's the output when you get an exception.

Comment: Look in `result1` in your debugger. What's in it? Also look in `us`. It's possible that `us` just doesn't have a property at `0`.

Comment: Yes, us may not be null, but the property you are accessing at index 0 certainly is.

Comment: @k_g but isn't the  indexes 0 and 3 are determined by the database?

Comment: Yes, and the database might be using a different storage numbering system/not have an entry at that point. If you have the database code, check the code, if not, check the specs.

Comment: I have it and I have the columns names does that help? because I'm not sure I understand the numbering you're talking about.

Comment: If you want to very easily find out if that index is null, merely loop 0 - 3 (or whatever your ceiling is) and do a `System.out.println()` on `us.getPropertyAsString(i)` - I bet you will find index 0 is null.

Comment: @k_g I still need you to answer:)

Answer (score 1):

Your `SoapObject` may not be null, but the index you are pointing to at `us.getPropertyAsString(0)` probably points to a null value. Please ensure that your object contains the properties you think it does.

You have the following code already:

```
for (int i = 0; i < apPhoto.length; i++) {
    SoapObject us = (SoapObject) result11.getProperty(i);

    apPhoto[i] = new ApartmentPhoto();
    apPhoto[i].id = Integer.parseInt(us.getPropertyAsString(0));
    apPhoto[i].image = us.getPropertyAsString(3);
}
```

Just add the following loop after declaring `us` as a quick test:

```
for(int j = 0; j < whateverYourCeilingIs; j++) {
    System.out.println(us.getPropertyAsString(j));
}
```

I think you will find index 0 is null.

Comment: Sorry but I don't know how to make sure! Is there any way to send you my web service code to check it? please:)

Comment: All day I've been checking and I'm sure nothing is wrong!!! that's why I need you to check it

Comment: I can't check it for you, I can only try to help diagnose, and this is my best guess. Take a look at the output from that and see if you are printing nulls

Comment: It is not null. any other suggestions?